# Как запросить и обработать таблицу

Tags: java, http

Начал изучать http только и хочется разобраться, можно ли своё расписание запилить с запросами к базе данных универа.
Есть сайт университета, на нём можно просматривать расписание. Как я понял, там делается POST запрос и прилетает что-то такое:

```
    </div>
    <div class="action_1">
        <input type="submit" name="ShowTT" value="Показать" id="ShowTT" />
        <div class="show chosen-container chosen-container-single"><a class="chosen-single button">Показать</a></div>
    </div>
</div>
<a id="HyperLink1" href="PrintPage.aspx?arg0=6702&amp;arg1=3&amp;arg2=2&amp;arg3=2&amp;arg4=1&amp;date=15.04.2019 0:00:00" target="_blank">Печать</a>
<br />
        <span id="lMessage"></span>
<table id="TT">
<caption>
    Расписание занятий на неделю с 15.04.2019</br>Факультет математики и информатики, дневная форма                                                                                        обучения, 2 курс, группа СДП-ПМ                            
</caption><tr class="row row-separator">
    <td colspan="6"></td>
</tr><tr class="row row-header">
    <td class="cell-header cell-date">Дата</td><td class="cell-header cell-time">Время</td><td class="cell-header cell-subgroup">Подгруппа</td><td class="cell-header cell-discipline">Дисциплина</td><td class="cell-header cell-staff">Преподаватель</td><td class="cell-header cell-auditory">Аудитория</td>
</tr><tr class="row row-separator">
    <td colspan="6"></td>
</tr><tr class="row row-spanned">
    <td class="cell-date" rowspan="5"><span class='day'>Понедельник</span> <span class='date'>15.04.2019</span></td><td class="cell-time">08:30-09:50</td><td class="cell-subgroup">на русском языке</td><td class="cell-discipline" colspan="1">Лекция (УСР) Технологии разр. платформенно-независ прилож.<span class='topic'></span></td><td class="cell-staff">ст.пр. Марыкин Михаил Эдуардович</td><td class="cell-auditory">ауд. -, Ожешко, 22</td>
</tr><tr class="row">
    <td class="cell-time">08:30-09:50</td><td class="cell-subgroup">на англ. языке</td><td class="cell-discipline" colspan="1">Лекция (УСР) Технологии разр. платформенно-независ прилож.</br><span class='topic'></span></td><td class="cell-staff">ст.пр. Шаплыко Денис Александрович</td><td class="cell-auditory">ауд. -, Ожешко, 22</td>
</tr><tr class="row">
```

Comment: Эм, где продолжение вопроса? Что конкретно вы хотите сделать? И в конце концов, чем вам не подходит расписание вашего универа?

Comment: Суть вопроса не понятна: Попробуйте задать более конкретный вопрос.

Comment: можно ли так сделать? И если да - то где и что об этом можно почитать?